# iOS action extension icon place

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-app-extension

I'm developing an Action Extension now, I find that my extension icon is on the bottom line.

How to get my extension to the same line of box and WeChat?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After asking help from Apple.I'm using the wrong extension.If you want your app extension on the first row, use Share extension, not Action Extension.